# Why does my fairly avarage system fail to run even a light distro?

Tags: boot, system-installation, performance, system-requirements

I have a system with 4GB RAM, 500GB hard disk and 2.1ghz intel i3 processor. Windows used to hang a lot so I tried Ubuntu which worked for a few days but then gave problems, then I tried Lubuntu and Xubuntu but every time I install it is extremely slow and I always run into new problems.

It also takes somewhere between 2-3 hrs to install any operating system. I don't think I should have these issues with this configuration.

My motherboard is changed from original one. Originally I had Acer AMD something but I got it changed, now it's Toshiba Intel i3.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: You didn't say which versions you installed. 16.04 may run faster than 20.04.

Comment: Have you checked the hard drive for problems?

Comment: Something seems wonky.  An install should take less than an hour on a slow system.  Your system should work decently unless your are pushing it to the limits.  Have a P4 system with 1.2GBs ram that runs okay on Lubuntu.

Comment: insufficient data -- you are asking us to guess. "*but then gave problem*" and "*always run into new problems*" do not provide adequate information to help you.

Comment: Just wondering if something was not changed that should have been when you had motherboard changed and is giving problems with OSs.

Answer (score 1):

Using a SSD or a faster hard drive could make it run faster. I installed linux on an (external) hard drive and it takes a few minutes to boot.